# Nokogiri on OS X 10.8

Tags: ruby, macos, nokogiri

I know there's a ton of questions about this here on SO, but I really can't manage to install Nokogiri on my OS X 10.8.3 system.

I did the rituals:

```
brew install libxml2 libiconv libxslt
brew link --force libxml2 libiconv libxslt
```

but I keep getting these errors after doing a `sudo gem install nokogiri`:

```
Fetching: nokogiri-1.5.5.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for libxml/parser.h... yes
checking for libxslt/xslt.h... yes
checking for libexslt/exslt.h... yes
checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... no
checking for iconv_open() in -liconv... no
checking for iconv_open() in -liconv... no
checking for libiconv_open() in iconv.h... no
checking for libiconv_open() in -liconv... no
checking for libiconv_open() in -liconv... no
-----
libiconv is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

The interesting thing is that the `libiconv` error is randomly alternated with a `libxml2` error.
I followed the instructions at http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html but it just doesn't work.

## Edit

I don't believe what just happened. Really, I don't.

```
brew uninstall libxml2 libiconv libxslt
```

It works now, `gem` installs it. It complained a little:

```
No definition for parse_memory

No definition for parse_file

No definition for parse_with

No definition for get_options

No definition for set_options
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rdoc/rdoc.rb:280: warning: conflicting chdir during another chdir block
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rdoc/rdoc.rb:287: warning: conflicting chdir during another chdir block
```

but at least in [Middleman](http://middlemanapp.com) (that's were I'm using it) it works like a charm. Am I crazy?

Comment: What does mkmf.log say?

Comment: Did you try the instructions under "homebrew 0.9"? The `--with-xml2-include` part? The reason is, homebrew install those modules in the `/usr/` directory and symlinks to `/usr/bin`. When you run `sudo stuff`, it may not find those libraries.

Comment: @Kashyap yep, I tried to use the options on the nokogiri site to force it to find the libs installed with Homebrew bit it wasn't successful.

Comment: Can you post the error log when you tried to do that? Does it still say it's unable to find iconv? Do you have the gem `iconv` installed? You can know that by running `ruby -e "require 'iconv'"`

Comment: @Kashyap Edited the question, does it make sense for you? (I never installed `iconv` through `gem`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What did actually work for me is this.

### Brew

After you installed `brew`, install the following libs:

```
brew install libxml2 libxslt
```

### RVM

Now, **in bash** (if you're on `zsh`, just issue `bash` to move to the bash shell) do:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails --autolibs=enabled
```

to get RVM (Ruby Version Manager). In your `bash|zshrc`, paste the following line:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

to load rvm on startup.

**Note** that if you didn't install the above libs with `brew`, the `rvm` installation will fail.

Restart the terminal and then issue:

```
rvm install 1.9.3 # or the version you like, 1.9.3 worked for nokogiri
```

And to use this version as the system default just issue:

```
rvm --default use 1.9.3
```

### Install nokogiri via `gem`

Now the `gem install nokogiri` command should work fine.

**Note** that omitting the `sudo` is fundamental when dealing with `rvm` and `gem` stuff. That's one of the things that I missed and made me go crazy.

Comment: I think only the first part of your solution is required, and furthermore, I don't see the need to (re)install 1.9.3, and whatsmore via RVM.